# finding the domain of a square root expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question given is

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{(x − 2)(x − 6)} 
$$

I have to find the domain of this function, so I take both expressions and compute when they are greater than or equals $0$ and get

$[2,\infty) \cup [6,\infty)$,

but this is wrong; any help why?

Comment: Remember that the product of two negative numbers is a positive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four comments:

1) To have $(x-2)(x-6)\ge 0$ and you assume they are positive (or zero) you must assume *BOTH* are positive and not that one or the other is positive.

SO you need $[2,\infty) \cap [6,\infty)$ and *not* $[2, \infty) \cup [6,\infty)$.

2) It's not enough to just write $[2,\infty) \cap [6,\infty)$.  You should figure out what $[2,\infty) \cap [6,\infty)$ *is*.

We need $x \ge 2$ *AND* $x\ge 6$.  If $x \le x < 6$ the $x \not \ge 6$ but if $x \ge 6$ then $x \ge 2$ so our domain is all $x \ge 6$ or in other words $[6,\infty)$.

3) It is possible they are both positive (or zero) but it's also possible they are both *negative* (or zero).

If $x-2 \le 0$ *AND* $x-6 \le 0$ we have $x \le 2$ and $x \le 6$.  So we need $(-\infty, 2]\cap (-\infty 6]$ which, by the same reasoning above id $(-\infty, 2]$.

4) So we need that *EITHER* they are both positive (or zero) and $x\in [6, \infty)$  *OR* they are are both negative (or zero) and $x \in (-\infty, 2]$.

So $x \in [6, \infty)\cup (-\infty, 2]$.

....

It is *VERY* important to understand the implications of "AND" and the implications of "OR".  Very different results and you must understand them *both* to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

You want the product of $x-2$ and $x-6$ to be non-negative.  That occurs when both are non-positive  or both are non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Both factors are positive when 6 <= x.
Both factors are negative when x <= 2.
The product is positive for all x in $(-\infty, 2] \cup [6,\infty)$.